# List of all layers in multi-page visio document

Tags: layer, visio

I have a Visio document with 40+ pages/tabs. Each page has a number of layers and I'm trying to generate a list of all the layers across the document so that I can confirm that naming conventions have been adhered to without having to go through each page individually.

Does anyone know if this is possible to output such a list
 e.g.

- **Page 1**
- foo_layer
- bar_layer
- **Page 2**
- foo_layer
- x_layer
  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible. You could use a VBA macro to accomplish the task for example, or an external script. Visio has a rich API; you could check out the official documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nikolay.
I was hoping to find something out of the box but VBA came to the rescue. In case this is useful to others here's my code:

```
Sub List_page_Layers()

Dim Pageobj As Visio.Page
Dim PageLayer As Visio.Layer
Dim myFile As String
Dim layerVal As String
Dim searchString as String
searchString = "SOME TEXT" 'This allows me to filter as there were a couple of pages I wasn't interested and all other pages had a common string in their name
myFile = "C:\\Temp\\Layers.txt"

Open myFile For Output As #1

For Each Pageobj In ActiveDocument.Pages
    If InStr(Pageobj.Name, searchString) Then
        For Each PageLayer In Pageobj.Layers
            layerVal = Pageobj.Name & " - " & PageLayer.Name

            Write #1, layerVal
        Next
    End If

Next
Close #1
End Sub
```

This outputs a text file with layer names which I can then use as needed